# how to set more than 2 filter in WHERE in mysql SELECT

Tags: mysql

hello i have mysql select. i'm going to select loc from core. This loc must select from rows which has  dateid=('".$dateid."') and location=('".$id."') also i need to add two condition in WHERE. I mean can i do this like a **WHERE dateid=('".$dateid."') AND location=('".$id."') AND BETWEEN '2012-10-1' AND '2012-10-4'"** this is not working.
how can i add this time span?

```
$SQL = "SELECT loc FROM core WHERE dateid=('".$dateid."') AND location=('".$id."')";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);
 if($result){
$db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$rs[$i]=$db_field[$select[$i]];}

}
```

can i add start date and end date in where?
how can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean add two condition in WHERE?

Comment: Remove braces surrounding your variables - they are not needed there.

Comment: @RomanNewaza: [Parentheses `()` are not braces `{}`](http://cutewriting.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/punctuation-tip-brackets-braces-and.html).

Comment: hello can i add BETWEEN '2012-10-1' AND '2012-10-4' in the WHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the braces in first two and add remaining two filters with `AND` operator. You should be good i.e.

```
  SELECT loc FROM core WHERE dateid=$dateid AND location=$id
       AND startdate = STR_TO_DATE('$startdate', '%d/%m/%y') 
       AND enddate = STR_TO_DATE('$enddate', '%d/%m/%y') ;
```

I am assuming `dateid` and `id` are numeric fields while `startdate` and `enddate` are string values containing date values e.g. `12/12/2012`.

Please use the right column and variable names. Also provide to date format of your string.

Comment: hello i want to set time span by start data and enddate

Comment: @ganaa In that case, use `between` e.g. `date_column between STR_TO_DATE('$startdate', '%d/%m/%y') and STR_TO_DATE('$enddate', '%d/%m/%y')`